# make BottomNavigationView in bottom even if i use layout_scrollFlags to scroll Tollbar

Tags: android

My problem is `BottomNavigationView` never shows unless I scroll up.
So when I scroll up toolbar is hidden and my `BottomNavigationView` shows up.
I want it to stay at then bottom.
So i think my problem is with  `app:layout_scrollFlags`.

main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            style="@style/ToolBar"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/selectlite"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

          <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"


        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        tools:listitem="@layout/ticket_cardview_service"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_personall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/cardview_light_background"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
        app:menu="@menu/personal_navigation_items"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I fixed punctuation and capitalization (to make it understandable)

Comment: Hey @alacoo, did  you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Dittimon Unfortunately no

Comment: Does anyone knew the answer? I cannot believe this is still an issue

Answer (score 0):

Move your BottomNavigationView outside of your CoordinatorLayout. It worked for me.

Something like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

      <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
          android:id="@+id/navigation_personall"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom"
          android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
          app:itemIconTint="@color/cardview_light_background"
          app:itemTextColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
          app:menu="@menu/personal_navigation_items"/>

      <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_above="@id/navigation_personall">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
            >

          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
              android:id="@+id/toolbar"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
              android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
              app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
              app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
              style="@style/ToolBar"/>

          <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
              android:id="@+id/tabs"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
              app:tabGravity="fill"
              app:tabMode="fixed"
              app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/selectlite"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            tools:listitem="@layout/ticket_cardview_service"/>

      </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```